# split url and store in array, object or string using javascript/nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, lodash

Lets say I have a URL such as /test-resource/test1-100/test2-200/test3-300

I want to split the url and store 100, 200 and 300 in a array, object or string.

Answer (score 1):

Here we go

```js
var str = '/test-resource/test1-100/test2-200/test3-300';
var re = /(test\d+)\-(\d+)/g;

var arr = [];

while( res = re.exec(str) ) {
  arr[res[1]] = res[2];
  alert('match:' + res[0] + ' property:' + res[1] + ' value:' + res[2]);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but most likely you will have to change the logic accordingly to the url params you have.

```
var x = "/test-resource/test1-100/test2-200/test3-300";
var y = x.split("/");
var one_hundred = y[2].split('-')[1];
var two_hundred = y[3].split('-')[1];
var three_hundred = y[4].split('-')[1];
```

Source:

- [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a functional approach using lodash:

```
_(url)
    .split('/')
    .map(_.bindKey(/\d+$/, 'exec'))
    .map(_.first)
    .compact()
    .map(_.ary(parseInt, 1))
    .value()
    // → [ 100, 200, 300 ]
```

Here's how it works:

- `split()` breaks the URL down into it's parts, so now you have an array.
- [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map) uses [bindKey()](https://lodash.com/docs#bindKey) to create a callback function that executes a regular expression against each URL part. So now you have an array of regular expression results.
- `map()` uses [first()](https://lodash.com/docs#first) to grab only the first item from the regular expression results. Now you have an array of number strings, or `undefined`.
- [compact()](https://lodash.com/docs#compact) removes the `undefined` items.
- `map()` uses `parseInt()` to transform the array of strings into an array of numbers. [ary()](https://lodash.com/docs#ary) makes sure only one argument is passed to `parseInt()`.